# Integral with absolut-value function

Tags: calculus, analysis

How do I seperate the following integral?

The integral of $|x^2-y|$ with $|y| \leq 1$ and $|x| \leq 1$. I know that the absolute value is positive for $x^2 \geq 1$ and negative for $x^2$ but I am getting the wrong answer when I write them as a sum of integrals. I think I chose wrong bounds.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how the integral is specified?  You can use \int to specify an integral marker...  For example, $$\int\int |x^2-y|dydx$$

Comment: First draw the region of integration, and then from there you can see how you can separate the region in appropriate parts.

Comment: @abiessu Isn't the domain $|x|\leq 1$, $|y|\leq 1$?

Comment: @alex: yes, but I only put in an example of how to show the integral...

Comment: @abiessu I beg your pardon, I hadn't got that.-)

Answer (score 0):

**Draw** the square with corners $(\pm 1,\pm 1)$ in all combinations. **Draw** the parabola $y=x^2$.

First, the region $A$ "above" the parabola. There $|x^2-y|=y-x^2$. So we want 
$$\iint_A (y-x^2)\,dx\,dy.$$
Integrate first (say) with respect to $y$, then with respect to $x$. We get
$$\int_{x=-1}^1\left(\int_{y=x^2}^1(y-x^2)\,dy\right)\,dx.$$
Next, the region $B$ "below" the parabola. We want
$$\iint_B (x^2-y)\,dx\,dy.$$
For the iterated integral, $y$ goes from $-1$ to $x^2$.

**Remark:** I would take advantage of symmetry, and in each case only integrate from $x=0$ to $x=1$, and at the end double the result obtained.